# Can anyone explain the unit for rate of expansion of universe?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, units, cosmological-inflation

If you google for 'what is rate of expansion of universe' you get

> Space itself is pulling apart at the seams, expanding at a rate of 74.3 plus or minus 2.1 kilometers (46.2 plus or minus 1.3 miles) per second per megaparsec (a megaparsec is roughly 3 million light-years).

Can anyone please explain what does the unit mean? what is 'per second per megaparsec'?
I believe *x* km/s would suffic the rate of expansion. Not sure what 'per megaparsec' specifies?

Comment: It means that the rate of expansion varies with distance.  The rate of separation of points zero distance apart is zero.  The rate for points separated by 1 megaparsec is 74.3 kilometers per second.  The rate for points separated by 2 megaparsec is 148.6 kilometers per second; etc. But definitely off topic here.

Comment: The Expansion Of Space:
X = D(2.4*10^-18)^s --- D=Distance, S=seconds  But this apply to a straight line and is calculated dofferent for area ...however, too involved of a calculation for such a small comment space.

Answer (score 2):

The hubble relation is:

$$v = H d$$

where $v$ is the velocity of the galaxy relative to the Milky way, and $d$ is the distance of the galaxy relative to the milky way.  The velocity is measured using [redshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift).  The distance is measured through a complicated series of [standard candles](http://universe-review.ca/R02-07-candle.htm), along with the relationship $I = \frac{I_{0}}{4\pi r^{2}}$.

If you notice, these are related by Hubble's constant $H$.  This tells us how fast something is moving apart, based on how far away it is.  Namely, it's the rate of expansion of the universe.  Since astronomers measure distance in a unit called a [parsec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsec), and velocity at these high speeds is naturally measured in km/s, we can see that the "natural" units astronomers use for $H$ are (km/s)/parsec., since that's the only way to get km/s out when you multiply by something measured in parsec.

Comment: Good, standard explanation. To be complete we need to mention that as far as the units go, the km and Mpc are fungible, so actually the SI unit of expansion is 1/s, roughly $H=1.7 \times 10^{-18}/s$ and the inverse of that is more or less the age of the universe.

Comment: Thank you -  I would generally recommend using this "per-second" version, as I find this purer version to be the most usable.

Answer (score 0):

As time goes along, everything in the universe expands by a dimensionless scale factor a(t).  This $a(t)$ is the scale factor seen in the [Robertson-Walker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) metric.  Some galaxy at a distance $x_0$  at time $t_0$, will be at $x(t)$ at time $t$.
$$
x(t)=a(t) \quad x_0
$$
Taking the derivative wrt t gives
$$
\dot{x}=\dot{a}\quad x_0
$$
and dividing by the first equation gives
$$
\frac{\dot{x(t)}}{x(t)}=\frac{\dot{a(t)}}{a(t)}\equiv H(t)
$$
where the Hubble Constant is a function of time and its value now is measured to be $H_0=70 [\frac{km/sec}{Mpc}]$ so we get the familiar "now" Hubble Law
$$
\dot{x}=H_0 x
$$
Astronomers like megaparsecs (Mpc) as a unit of distance, where 
$$
1 [Mpc] = 3*10^6[lyrs] = 3 * 10^{22}[m]
$$
The Hubble Constant can be expressed in may different units.  For example
$$
H_0=70[\frac{km/sec}{Mpc}]*10^3[\frac{m}{km}]*\frac{1}{3*10^{22}}[\frac{Mpc}{m}]
=2*10^{-18}[\frac{m/sec}{m}]
$$
or
$$
c*H_0=70[\frac{km/sec}{Mpc}]*10^3[\frac{m}{km}]*\frac{1}{3*10^{22}}[\frac{Mpc}{m}]*3*10^8[\frac{m}{sec}]
=7*10^{-10}[\frac{m}{sec^2}]
$$

which is an acceleration in nice everyday mks units.

Comment: Going by [standard usage](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/prefixes.html), mpc is actually a *milliparsec*. You want Mpc instead.

Comment: Also where did that $c$ come from in the last line?

Comment: @Kyle: Thank you, I have added c*H to the last equation.  This is an example of getting in the habit of leaving c's out of equations.  I alsochanged mpc to Mpc.

Answer (score -1):

**Can anyone please explain what does the unit mean? what is 'per second per megaparsec'? I believe x kms per sec would suffic the rate of expansion. Not sure what 'per megaparsec' specifies?**

The mega-parsec unit is required because each mega-parsec of distance is expanding at a rate of 74.3 km/s. So, if two side-by-side mega-parsecs expand in one second, the total expansion is 148.6 km. The "per mega-parsec" forces you to do a summation over vast distances.

Great question BTW!